# Error message when using strptime, wrong format even though it appears correct. What's going on?

Tags: datetime, format, strptime

Why do these date formats not match? I am getting an error message that shows the date in question and says it is not in the format that appears to be in, %Y-%m-%d. What's wrong here?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have the arguments to `strptime` reversed.  Instead of this:

```
  datetime.datetime.strptime('%Y-%m-%d', '2017-08-23')
```

do this:

```
  datetime.datetime.strptime('2017-08-23', '%Y-%m-%d')
```